# Is there WhatsApp SDK to get the Chat Log(Only to get time of last chat and contact number)?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, whatsapp

I would like to use some features of WhatsApp in my mobile app(android and ios).
I want to get the chat log(Time of WhatsApp chat with friends) in my app.
I don't need the chat texts but the last chatting time and contact number.
Is it possible? or is there any SDK available for to get this feature? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, **No**.

WhatsApp don't provide an official SDK and any SDKs out there violate WhatsApp's TOF and will get your user's account blocked.

See [this page](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/he/android/28000012) in WhatsApp's FAQ

Answer (score 0):

You can try integrating Mobile Instant Messaging SDK by Hyphenate. Hyphenate supports both Mobile and Web SDK with rich features (one-to-one chat, group chat, chat room, video/voice calling, and almost the random features as WhatsApp has) and very reliable services.

https://hyphenate.io/